# Change the master page when clicking a button in master

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, master-pages

I am having three master pages like `Master-Green, Master-Bule, Master-Red`. In each master page having three buttons named as `green, blue and red`.
Now my `default master is green`,

It's assigned a page `Default.aspx`. At this time three button also display on the top.

How to make so clicking "blue" button means the Master-Blue shold be master page for the current page?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have 3 CSS files and only 1 Master Page?

Comment: This is exactly what ASP.Net themes were invented for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx - on clicking your button, you'd just change the page theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the Master Page use input type submit button

<`input` type="`submit`" name="`btnGreen`" value="Green" />

<`input` type="`submit`" name="`btnBlue`" value="Blue" />

2.Then from the code behind you can check the name of the button clicked, in the Request object in the Page_PreInit event

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["btnGreen"] != null)
        {
            Page.MasterPageFile = "/Green.Master";
        }
        else if (Request["btnBlue"] != null)
        {
            Page.MasterPageFile = "/Blue.Master";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It return the following error Error: The virtual path '/Master-Red.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Comment: Mohammad,Its Working fine. Shall i use image button instead of button.

Comment: Yes you can do that , The point to remember is the name of the server control rendered will be a slightly different, it will be something  like "ctl00$btnRed". You can check the source of the browser and find the name. Take that name and append a ".x" or ".y". So the name will like if (Request["ctl00$btnRed.x"]).  Please check Request.Form.AllKeys in watch window you will find how the image button name comes to the server

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with dynamic master pages might look easy at first sight but it's a little tricky.

Consider the following:

- A MasterPage is actually considered as a child control of the page, therefore, its life-cycle is like any other control on the page
- In order to change the MasterPage at runetime, it has to be done in the `PreInit` event of the page (remember that controls do not have this event, therefore the MasterPage does not have it either)
- As a reminder, the `PreInit`, `Init`, and `Load` events of the page life cycle work as follows: The page's `PreInit` event is fired, followed by all the `Init` events of the page's child controls (including the MasterPage), when all child `Init` events have been raised, the page's `Init` event is fired and finally the page's `InitComplete` event is fired indicating all `Init` events have been processed. The `Load` events work the other way around, the page's `Load` event is fired first, followed by all the child control's `Load` events and at the end, the page's `LoadComplete` event.
- The *Post back event* that caused the page's post back is raised after all child control's `Load` events have been fired but before the page's `LoadComplete` event
- In the `PreInit` event you do not have access to the page ViewState

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Quick Look:

[image]

So why is this so important?

In your example you have three buttons, each time a button is pressed, you need to change the MasterPage, but the MasterPage must be changed in the `PreInit` event of the page, but your button handler is processed after that, so the tricky part is to call `Server.Transfer` to re-process the page.

Note. Since you are allowing the user to personalize the MasterPage, you need a way store his preferences, usually you would use a cookie, or a database. In this sample I am going to use the `Session` object for simplicity but you can change it to fit your needs.

So this would look something like:

#### Master page code behind

```
protected void blueMasterPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Session["master"] = "BlueMasterPage";
    this.Server.Transfer(this.Request.RawUrl);
}
```

#### In the page code behind

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Session["master"] != null)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = string.Format("~/{0}.master", (string)this.Session["master"]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you do not use `Server.Transfer` you won't see the changes to the page's MasterPage until the next time you do a post to the page

So this was tricky, and in my opinion, we should be able to do the same easier, one more time the ASP.Net page's life cycle doesn't help at all.

You can always follow the @AndreCalil suggestion about using just one master page and different CSS layouts for your site

### Edit 1

One thing that I forgot to mention, is that you need to set the master page in all your pages consuming the dynamic MasterPage, so the best way to do it, is create a *base page* and inherit from it, and in the base page write the code in the `PreInit` event to set the MasterPage